Problem with user authentication in django
For a reason unknown to me, when authenticating a user, I enter the following data: email and password, as a result, super users are authenticated, but ordinary users are not.
What can be done about this? Has anyone encountered such a problem? Please help me solve this, I'm completely new to Django.
Here are the files in the project (if you need any other files, write):
views.py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from users.models import User

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        # password2 = request.POST.get("password2")
        phone_number = request.POST.get("phone_number")

        user = User (
            username = username,
            email = email, 
            password = password,
            phone_number = phone_number
        )
        user.save()
        return redirect('main:index')
    return render(request, 'users/register.html')

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('Authenticate!')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('No Login!')
    return render(request, 'users/login.html')


models.py
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from users.managers import CustomUserManager

class User (AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=30)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(region="IN", unique=True, null=True, blank=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

managers.py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email=None, password=None, username=None, **extra_fields):
        if email:
            email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)    
        user.email = email
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, username=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        return self._create_user(email, password, username, **extra_fields)
    
    def create_superuser(self, email=None, password=None, username=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        return self._create_user(email, password, username, **extra_fields)

admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'username')

settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

I am waiting for the authentication to work and the created users to be able to log in to my site. I would also like to understand in more detail why the superuser can be authenticated, but the user created on the site cannot.

What do you mean by "super users are authenticated, but ordinary users are not." ? What result are you expected ? How do you check if user is logged or not ?

I have a page with the login form, where I fill in the data: email and password, and then use the button to send this data to the user_login function. In the meantime, different users are stored in the database: regular ones who have registered on my site and admins. So when you click a button on the site, if I write the correct email and password of the admin, the inscription is displayed: Authenticate! , and when entering the data of an ordinary user, the inscription: No Login! . So it shouldn't be, what is it connected with?

Why are you subclassing User and BaseUserManager?  All of this code could be converted to a few lines if you use the builtin django.contrib.auth package.

I use all this to realise the login to the user's profile in the future with the help of several options: using email and phone number. Is it possible to realise this without BaseUserManager and the User class?
